# Google Maps add waypoints in the correct order

Tags: google-maps

I wanted to add the function to change the route by dragging the point of the route.
It is working for 1 point, but the next points are added after the first.
When I drag at the end, and then at the beginning, it will go over the end point end then go back to the start.
I added the points from the result waypoints and give it to the calculation.

```
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
      ges += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
      for (var y = 0; y < myroute.legs[i].via_waypoints.length; y++) {
          waypoints.push({
            location: myroute.legs[i].via_waypoints[y],
            stopover: false
          });
        };
```

I tried it with optimizeWaypoints, but it didn't work too.

```
    var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: ende,
        waypoints: waypoints,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
    };
```

It is shown right on the map, but in the diagram its shown wrong.
(The order how its dragged)

```
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

      elevationService.getElevationAlongPath({
          path: response.routes[0].overview_path,
              samples: SAMPLES
      }, plotElevation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,
i didn't clear the variable after dragging.
So the route was always added after dragging